# How do I create multiple instances of the same object using different spring contexts for junit integration tests?

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration

I would like to use spring annotations in an integration test to load different instances of the same object with different applicationContexts (yet using the same configuration xml). Below is a simple example to represent my issue:

My junit test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:CarContext.xml")
public class CarRaceTest
{
    @Autowired
    Car car1;

    @Autowired
    Car car2;

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        car1.displayParts();
        car2.displayParts();
    }

}
```

My Car class:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Car
{
    @Autowired
    private ElectricalSystem electricalSystem;

    @Autowired
    private Alternator alternator;

    public void displayParts()
    {
        System.out.println("Parts for car: " + this.toString());
        System.out.println(electricalSystem.toString());
        System.out.println(alternator.toString());
    }

    public void raceQuarterMile()
    {
    }
}
```

ElectricalSystem class:

```
@Component
public class ElectricalSystem
{
    @Autowired
    private Alternator alternator;
}
```

Alternator class:

```
@Component
public class Alternator
{
}
```

contents of CarContext.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="springTest"/>
```

As you can see from the example for a single car the Alternator may be referenced by multiple other components/systems - all needing to reference a singleton instance. Yet for my integration test to put two cars up against each other I need each car to have its own application context so I have different alternators in each car.

This is the output I get for the above code:

```
Parts for car: springTest.Car@3ea20bc2
springTest.ElectricalSystem@b20dae
springTest.Alternator@29a01add
Parts for car: springTest.Car@4e43b884
springTest.ElectricalSystem@b20dae
springTest.Alternator@29a01add
```

Notice how my two cars have the exact same electrical systems and alternators - not what I want.

Using context.getBean with two different application contexts I have been able to get it to work as expected with the following Junit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:CarContext.xml")
public class CarRaceTest
{

    private String contextFile = "classpath:CarContext.xml";

    private ApplicationContext appContext1;
    private ApplicationContext appContext2;

    Car car1;
    Car car2;

    public CarRaceTest()
    {
        this.appContext1 = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(this.contextFile);
        this.appContext2 = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(this.contextFile);
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        car1 = appContext1.getBean(Car.class);
        car2 = appContext2.getBean(Car.class);

        car1.displayParts();
        car2.displayParts();
    }
}
```

With the following output:

```
Parts for car: springTest.Car@247de4f1
springTest.ElectricalSystem@45419cee
springTest.Alternator@56a5f0c7
Parts for car: springTest.Car@2862c542
springTest.ElectricalSystem@6c8484c4
springTest.Alternator@70289784
```

How can I accomplish these same results with annotations without calling .getbean()?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct -- Spring is unable to swap your instance level reference with a new one with a field accessor; it's set once by the `@Autowired` annotation, and then everything just references the singleton of that field. I believe your question can be solved using Spring's `lookup-method` attribute, explained with examples, here: [Java code geeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/05/spring-lookup-method-example.html)